# how to save data in one model from another controller in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have two controller name as ProductsController and Categories Controller and have there models.I have loaded Category model in ProductsController using

```
public function beforeFilter(){


        $this->loadModel('Category');
    }
```

In ProductsController When I use

```
$data = $this->Category->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('product_id'=>$id)));
```

it will return Value so that I can retrieve data from Category model .But I try to Save data in Category model from productsController using

```
$this->Category->save($this->request->data);
```

It doesnot work.When I debug to to see what it return,I get debug result as

```
\app\controller\ProductsController.php (line 74)
false
```

How to solve this problem any help?

Comment: which cakephp version you are using ?

Comment: Without at least seeing the code of your products controller, and the data you're trying to save it's not possible to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to print data in `$this->request->data` before save and also print sql log
like

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->request->data);
$this->Category->save($this->request->data);
$log=$this->Category->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
echo "<pre>";print_r($log);exit;
```

and make sure you have set debug to 2 in core.php

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: @AD7six yeah you are right but want to add answer in proper formate so it can help to any newbi, thats why,still am sorry for this

Comment: It's good advice (though you can use `debug();` to avoid writing pre+print_r), but it's just that: advice. It's not an answer, and cannot be an answer until the Author provides more information/code.

Comment: @AD7six yeah will keep in mind,thanks for suggestion